# How to include a c-header with constants in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm developing a Simulink modell with many C-s-functions. For an easier handling I want to use constants in the c-s-function as in the simulink-modell. So I have a c-header with preprocesser constants like:

```
#define THIS_IS_A_CONSANT 10
```

And there is the question:
How it is possible to include this in Simulink in this way I can use THIS_IS_A_CONSANT for example in a constant source like a workspace-variable?

Thanks and regards
Alex

Comment: As this is not really about `C`, but rather how to parse a text file in Simulink, I think you will get more answers by removing the `C` tag.

Comment: This is only peripherally a Simulink question. Using MATLAB you need to parse the c file to extract the constant and create a MATLAB Workspace variable. Then you can incorporate that workspace variable into Simulink in the usual way

Comment: Hm - is there only the way along the Matlab workspace? Is there no way more directly? (C-header -> Simulink)
What does it mean to parse the C-header? In the Matlab-help I don't find a suitable command for this...

Comment: You could use set_param to put the value into the block dialog directly, but since you have to write m-code anyway, and it is recommended to parameterize models (with workspace parameters), that would seem unadvisable.  You won't find a function to explicitly pass a header/c file.  It's a very unusual thing to want to do.  However all the functionality to read and parse text files (see textscan, fgetl, regexp, and similar functions) exists so you'll need to piece it together yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is functionality in Simulink that will allow you to include custom C header files that define constants, variables, etc.; however, as far as I know (and as one might expect) this really is only pertinent in cases where code is being generated and compiled.

So, for the most part, this particular functionality is only relevant when you are using Simulink Coder to generate a stand-alone executable from your model.  For example, [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FVLWO9/) shows how to include parameters stored in an external header file during code generation through the use of [Simulink.Parameter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.parameter.html) objects with [Custom Storage Classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/custom-storage-classes.html) and the [Code Generation - Custom Code Pane](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ref/code-generation-pane-custom-code.html) under the model's Configuration Parameters.

[This link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/macro-definitions-define.html) from the Simulink doc shows how to use the *#define* custom storage class to achieve similar results.

However, it sounds like neither of these really solve your issue, as you want to make use of the code in the header file during simulation.

That said, considering that there are elements in Simulink, such as Stateflow Charts and MATLAB Function blocks, that generate and build code "under the hood" during simulation, it's (at least hypothetically) possible that you might be able to use some of the concepts described above to access the values in your header file from one of those elements during simulation.  For example, I was successfully able to access *preprocessor macros* in a Stateflow chart just by going to the [Simulation Target->Custom Code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/simulation-target-pane-custom-code.html) pane under Configuration Parameters and including the text **#include "header.h"** under *Include custom C code in generated: Header file*.  (In this case, header.h contained the line of C code that you included in your post)

Although it seems like you should be able to extend this functionality further, this really was the limit of what I was able to achieve as far as accessing the header file during simulation was concerned.  For example, I know that running a model in [Rapid Accelerator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/acceleration.html) mode actually generates and builds code under the hood, so seemingly you should be able to use some combination of the techniques I described above to be able to access values from the header file during simulation. It looks like the code that Rapid Accelerator mode generates doesn't respect all of the settings defined by those techniques in the same way that Simulink/Embedded Coder do, though, so I just kept running into compilation errors. (Although maybe I'm just missing some creative combination of settings that could make that work).

Hopefully that helps explain Simulink's abilities (and limitations) regarding the inclusion of C header files.  So to summarize, according to the links included above, what you are asking for is *almost* barely possible, but in practice... not really.

---

So if really all you want is to be able to create workspace variables out of the *preprocessor #define's* in your header file, it probably is just easiest to manually parse the file with a MATLAB script, as had previously been suggested in the comments. Here is a quick-and-dirty script that loads in a header file, iterates over each line, uses a regular expression (which you can improve upon if needed) to parse *#define* statements, and then calls *eval* to create variables from the parsed input.

```
filename = 'header.h';
pattern = '^\s*#define\s*(\w*)\s*(\d*\.?\d+)';
fid = fopen(filename);
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
   tokens = regexp(tline, pattern,'tokens','once');
   if(numel(tokens) == 2)
       eval([tokens{1} ' = ' tokens{2}]);
   end
   tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

You could put this code in a callback so that it will execute every time you load your model.  Just goto File->Model Properties->Model Properties, click on the Callbacks tab, and then place the code under whichever callback you desire (such as PreLoadFcn if you want it to run immediately before the model loads).